# Create a task with a integrated google form API

Tags: google-classroom

With the graphical user interface of google classroom it is possible to create a task with a quiz. In this mode google forms wil be integrated and the teacher can store the questions that will be shown to the students.
How is it possible to create such a task with the Google API ?

Thanks for every answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to create a quiz assignment using the Classroom API. If that is true, then you would need to use [`courses.courseWork.create`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/create) to fulfill your goals. Here you have a reference of the [request body](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#resource:-coursework) that you can use to complete your request. Please, don't hesitate to ask me if you are still facing doubts.